# AnyVal and Opaque type can't derive derivings.Mirror?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, compile-time, scala-macros, scala-3

1. Scala3's derivings.Mirror does not seem to be able to derive value classes or opaque types that inherit from AnyVal.
   Is there any way to achieve this other than parsing the signature in the macro?

```scala
  case class Foo(value: String)
  case class Bar(value: String) extends AnyVal
  opaque type Hoo = Long

  inline def derive[A] {
    summonFrom[Result[A]] {
      case x: Result[A] => x
      case _: Mirror.Of[A] => ???
      case _ => error("Derive failed")
    }
  }

  derive[Foo] // success
  derive[Bar] // Derive failed
  derive[Foo] // Derive failed
```

2. Why is there no Mirror in the case class that inherits from AnyVal?

```scala
case class Id(value: String) extends AnyVal // Don't match `_: Mirror.Of[Id]`
```

3. Is it possible to explore implicit conversions from arbitrary types in Summoning Implicits Selectively and derive the type before the conversion?

```scala
  inline def derive[A] {
    summonFrom[Result[A]] {
      case x: `[T] => scala.Conversion[Result[T], Result[A]] => x[T](derive[T])
      case _ => error("Derive failed")
    }
  }
```

I don't know the difference between macro and compile operation...

Comment: What is `Result` here?

Comment: Note that inline methods aren't allowed at all when opaque types are in scope (which feels odd, I'd only expect the compiler to disallow opaque types inside inline methods).

Comment: > ` What is Result here? ` This can be anything. For example, it can be Codec[T]. This is the type of the derived result.

Comment: Okay, that looks very strange to someone who is not familiar with Dotty and the internals of Scala3.